# gnuplot plot data from two files: in one x coordinate, in other y

Tags: unix, plot, gnuplot, concatenation

I have two files: one with x coordinates, and other with y.

Is there a way to plot this two files in one graph using gnuplot?
Or is there a way to concat row by row this two files?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is not a way to plot the x coordinate from one file and the y coordinate from another natively in gnuplot.

If you use a bash-like shell, you can use the command

```
paste x_data.dat y_data.dat > xy_data.dat
```

to combine files row-by row.  If you want to put this command into a gnuplot script, you can do so like this:

```
plot "<paste x_data.dat y_data.dat"
```

Answer (score 12):

There is an easier way to do what you ask, directly from within gnuplot. Try with:

```
plot "< join file1.dat file2.dat" using 1:2 with lines
```

If both files contain only one column, then the above command will print them one against the other.

The `join` command is also useful to perform arithmetic operations involving columns from different files; for example, if both files have two columns, then

```
plot "< join file1.dat file2.dat" using 1:($2+$4) with lines
```

will plot the first column of the first file against the sum between the second column of the first and second file.

The `join` command is part of the [GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html). My Mac has them installed by default; I guess this is the case for most Linux systems. If you use Windows, have a look at [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

**Source**: the gnuplot mailing list (http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/combining-data-from-different-input-files-td3528.html).