# Adding/multiplying heatmaps in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

Is it possible with gnuplot to perform an operation on data (adding/multiplying) from two data files to generate a heatmap with the result of the operation ?

Ex: I have two files each with 4 columns, where

- Col1: X coordinate
- Col2: Y coordiante
- Col3: Value
- Col4: Uncertainty

I want to multiply the columns 3 of each file.

I wondered if something similar exists/would work in gnuplot, like ...

```
splot 'first.dat' using 1:2:(v=$3), 'second.dat' using 1:2:(v*$3)
```

I have been able to do this with two columns from the same file

```
splot 'first.dat' using 1:2:($3*$4)
```

Comment: Yes, it is (somehow) possible. People here expect that you show your own attempts and your code how far you have gotten and asking for help with a specific coding problem. Additionally, you should show the structure of your data (e.g. some example lines) to avoid wild guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar question has already been answered:
[gnuplot plot data from two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549004/gnuplot-plot-data-from-two-files-in-one-x-coordinate-in-other-y)

In your case it will look like that:

```
splot "<paste first.dat second.dat" u 1:2:($3*$6)
```

Note that all columns from both files are present, therefore you have to "skip" the ones from the second file.

Comment: Great ! So simple - many thanks. Probably my search was too narrow, so I didn't find the other post.

Answer (score 1):

The OP apparently runs Linux or MacOS. @Eldrad's nice and short solution won't work with Windows. Of course, you can install additional programs like gnuwin, awk, etc...

A platform independent and gnuplot-only (bit more complicated) solution is the following.
You load the [files 1:1 into datablocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54600172/7295599) and print these datablocks into a new datablock by appending each line. Assumption is of course that the two files have the same number of lines.

**Code:**

```
### plot data from different files combined with mathematical operation
# platform independent gnuplot-only solution
reset session

Windows = GPVAL_SYSNAME[:7] eq "Windows" ? 1 : 0   # otherwise Linux or MacOS

FILE = "first.dat"
Data = "$Data1"
if (Windows) { load '< echo   '.Data.' ^<^<EOD  & type "'.FILE.'"' }
else         { load '< echo "\'.Data.'   <<EOD" & cat  "'.FILE.'"' }

FILE = "second.dat"
Data = "$Data2"
if (Windows) { load '< echo   '.Data.' ^<^<EOD  & type "'.FILE.'"' }
else         { load '< echo "\'.Data.'   <<EOD" & cat  "'.FILE.'"' }

set print $Data
    do for [i=1:|$Data1|] {
        print $Data1[i][1:strlen($Data1[i])-1]."\t".$Data2[i]
    }
set print

splot $Data u 1:2:($3*$6)
### end of code
```